# How to run Corba on different computers via lan

Tags: java, web, corba

Resently I learned how to run CORBA app on single PC by this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BpefT4giUoU
I have done the same and everything worked well on single pc. But I need to run corba app on two PC's via lan and I don't know how to do it. Maby some config of of client ORBD? I tried to run orbd and server on one PC with -ORBInitialPort and ORBInitialHost params and run client on different PC with ORBInitialPort and ORBInitialHost from remote ORBD, but it doesn't helped

Comment: "it doesn't helped" is not just bad English, it's also a bad error description. Be more specific, please!

Answer (score 0):

As host you have to specify the host name or ip address of the system running the server, when you start it with localhost it will only be accessible from the same system.